# Insert string into plot

Tags: plotting

I want to place a string in a plot by using data coordinates.

I tried the following:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, Epilog -> Inset[Grid[{{"string"}}, 
  Frame -> All], {2, -1.1}]]
```

The problem is that "string" is not any more seen, since it is out of plot range.

[image]

How can I place a single string at any position inside or outside the plot frame, by using data coordinates?

Comment: @Kuba: The lower part of the string with the frame around is not fully seen.

Comment: ok, so if I understand this correctly: You want the plot range to adapt so that it includes the string, wherever you have placed it?

Comment: @C. E. What should I do to place the string for example below the value `2` at the horizontal axis? The plot range should not be changed.

Comment: @Kuba: `PlotRangeClipping -> False ` helps not if I want to use e.g. `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, Epilog -> Inset[Grid[{{"string"}}, Frame -> All], {2, -1.35}], 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]`

Comment: Thank you Kuba. This is the solution.

Comment: Try also this: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    None}, {{1, {2, 
      Column[{Style["2", 12, Red], Style["string", 12, Red]}, 
       Alignment -> Center]}, 3, 4, 5, 6}, None}}]` and play with the `Style`.